# How to define non-clustered index include clause in a JPA Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, indexing, include, entity

I have an entity, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = {
        @Index(name = "myModel_name_index", columnList = "name")
})
public class MyModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private boolean active;
    @Column(unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String value;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

When a query will be sent to Microsoft Sqlserver by Spring Data JPA like this:

```
select count(*) from myModell where name='anything';
```

then myModel_name_index will be used.

When a query will be sent to Microsoft Sqlserver by Spring Data JPA like this:

```
select name, active, description,price from myModell where name='anything';
```

then myModel_name_index will not be used!

The explain plan result told me, An index should be created as

```
create nonclustered index myModel_name_index on myModell(name) include(active, description,price)
```

My question: how can the Include clause be defined on entity? Which solution can be used?

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done, and you also shouldn't rely on JPA/Hibernate for schema management. Use a tool like Liquibase or Flyway to manage your schema, which both allow you to take full control of the DDL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is Flyway able to manage this feature?

Comment: Since you manage your DDL like the `create index` statement in files where you write this exact SQL, Flyway obviously can handle this. But either way, there are many reasons for a database not using your index. Maybe the data set with which you are testing is too small and the DB gains no benefit from using the index (because all data sits in one disk block). Maybe your statistics are out of date and it thinks it's not worth it. Or maybe the condition matches more than 10% of the rows and due to that chooses not to use the index.